# How do I integrate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty {x^2\over(x^2+1)^2}\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm hinted to use $x = a\tan(\theta)$, but after simplifying everything, I'm ending up with a bunch of $\sec(\theta)$ to powers of 2 and 4 on the numerator and denominator. Nothing is cancelling out.

Comment: Are you using trig identities to simplify?

Comment: It is easy, it is $\displaystyle{\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{cosh(x)^3}}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $x=\tan u$. Note $\mathrm{d}x=\sec^2 u \mathrm{d}u$.  The integral becomes $$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{\tan^2 u }{\sec^2 u}\;\mathrm{d}u  =\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\sin^2 u\;\mathrm{d}u =\int_{-\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1-\cos 2u}{2}\mathrm{d}u=\frac{\pi}{2}$$
As $$\frac{\tan^2 x}{\sec^2 x}=\frac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^2 x} \times \frac{\cos^2 x}{1}=\sin^2 x$$And from using the [half angle formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Double-angle.2C_triple-angle.2C_and_half-angle_formulae).

Comment: It's told to use x = a*tan(theta) as a substitution. With that, I can't get the simple sec^2 at the bottom.

Comment: @Goldname You can. I substituted with $a=1$.

Comment: OH. And I thought $\dfrac{\tan^2 x}{\sec^2 x}=\dfrac{\sin^2 x}{\cos^4 x}$ lol

Comment: @Ovi That's OK.

Comment: I'm not quite understanding. How can you just assume a = 1?

Comment: @Goldname I didn't assume it. The hint said that it was of the form $a \tan x$, and $a$ was an unspecified constant we needed to find. Thus, the answer is $1$.

Answer (score 8):

If $a>0$ we have
$$ I(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{a+x^2}=\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{a}}\tag{1} $$
hence:
$$ -I'(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{(a+x^2)^2}=\frac{\pi}{2a\sqrt{a}}\tag{2} $$
and by $(1)$ and $(2)$ at $a=1$ we get:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}\,dx = I(1)+I'(1) = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: +1 for this answer!! But @JackD'Aurizio I was that you answered a question about the derivation of the sun constant formula, now that was a repost by someone else of my question. So I tried to answer that question but I was that you used a equality involving integrals for $\theta$, so I reposted my original question on physics stackexhcange and can you explain there where you found that integral equality? (http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/316550/sun-constant-formula-derivation-using-keplers-laws-of-planetary-motion)

Answer (score 4):

Setting
$$
x=\tan\theta,
$$
we have

\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}\,dx&=&\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\tan^2\theta}{(\tan^2\theta+1)^2}\cdot(1+\tan^2\theta)\,d\theta=2\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{\tan^2\theta}{\tan^2\theta+1}\,d\theta\\
&=&2\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{\tan^2\theta+1}\right)\,d\theta=\pi-2\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos^2\theta\,d\theta\\
&=&\pi-\int_0^{\pi/2}(1+\cos2\theta)\,d\theta=\pi-\dfrac{\pi}{2}=\dfrac{\pi}{2}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 3):

HINT: we have $$\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}=\frac{x^2+1-1}{x^2+1}=1-\frac{1}{x^2+1}$$
in the corrected case write
$$\frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)^2}=x\cdot \frac{x}{(x^2+1)^2}$$ and use Integration by parts

Comment: Unfortuantely the question has since been edited.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{2}}dx=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2}}{\left(1+x^{2}\right)^{2}}dx$$ $$\stackrel{x^{2}=u}{=}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{1/2}}{\left(1+u\right)^{2}}du=B\left(\frac{3}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$ which follows from the identity $$B\left(m+1,n+1\right)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{u^{m}}{\left(1+u\right)^{m+n+2}}du$$ and obviously $B(x,y)$ is the [Beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BetaFunction.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use partial fractions to break up the fraction and integrate separately from there, or use a trig sub and let $x=\tan(\theta)$ then simplify using trig identities to integrate. Finally, use limits to evaluate the bounds of $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Put $x=\tan(z)$  then integrate changing limits

Answer (score 0):

Glaisher's theorem says that if $f(x)$ is an even meromorphic function with series expansion around $x = 0$ given by:

$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (-1)^k a_k x^{2k}$$

then:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) dx = \pi a_{-\frac{1}{2}}$$

if the integral converges. Here $a_{-\frac{1}{2}}$ looks to be an ill defined quantity, it is defined by analytic continuation after expressing the expansion coefficients in terms of factorials and replacing those factorials by gamma functions. In practice it just boils down to substituting $k = -\frac{1}{2}$ in an analytic formula for the expansion coefficients.

In this case the series expansion is easily found, e.g. by considering the geometric series for $\frac{1}{1+x}$, differentiating that series term by term to obtain the series for $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$, multiplying by $x$ to obtain the series for $\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}$ and finally replacing $x$ by $x^2$ to obtain the result:

$$\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-1)^k (-k) x^{2k}$$

We thus have $a_{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{1}{2}$, the integral is thus equal to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Using integration by parts:
$$\pi=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac1{1+x^2} \mathrm d x=\frac x{1+x^2}\bigg|_{-\infty}^{+\infty}+\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{2x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}\mathrm d x$$
Hence:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}\mathrm d x=\frac{\pi}2 $$